# Conda Installation of Environment (PyFerret) unsuccessful

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I try installing PyFerret on my Mac. My goal is to be able to call PyFerret within my jupyter notebook or my terminal.
I initially downloaded it using the commands from: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyferret
The website suggested to type in one of the following commands into the terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyferret
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken pyferret
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyferret
```

I did not read the instructions carefully and installed the three of them. Now I do not know how to uninstall them as the commands below did not seem to work:

```
conda remove 
conda uninstall
```

The installation of PyFerret here seems to be different to what it is described here: 
https://github.com/NOAA-PMEL/PyFerret/blob/master/README.md
It says "Allow miniconda to add its initialization code to your start-up scripts (e.g., $HOME/.bashrc) and open a new login window when the installation is complete. " I do not know how to allow anaconda to do this.
However, i did use the installation command:

```
conda create -n FERRET -c conda-forge pyferret ferret_datasets --yes
```

Which according to the second link should be enough and one can activate the environment with

```
conda activate FERRET
```

to which my terminal complained:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I ended up initializing it with:

```
conda init -bash
```

Which then allowed me to activate PyFerret. However, once active the only change I was able to notice was that the name of my terminal had change to **(FERRET)Mac:Username$** . I tried giving a few commands but I was unable to verify that PyFerret worked nor I was able to call it on my Jupyter Notebook , and unable to delete all the extra stuff I downloaded with the first link.
I am unsure as to why the Anaconda website has different installation instructions for the same environment, and why I was unable to uninstall the extra ones I got in by mistake.
I hope this is clear enough and that I can get your help soon.
However, this only changed the "name" of the command line to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Conda can only install one version of a package at a time, it would suffice to reinstall the one you actually want, presumably

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyferret
```

and it will replace whatever other build you might have installed. As for the activation, the command should be

```
conda init bash
```

or if on Mac OS X Catalina

```
conda init zsh
```

To use a Conda environment in a Jupyter notebook, you should install `ipykernel` in the environment you want to use as a kernel:

```
conda install -n FERRET ipykernel
```

and `nb_conda_kernels` in the env that has Jupyter (usually **base**), e.g.,

```
conda install -n base nb_conda_kernels
```

Always launch `jupyter notebook` with that latter env activated, e.g.,

```
conda activate base
jupyter notebook
```

Then you can select the `FERRET` environment as your kernel when creating a new notebook (or change existing notebooks to use it).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Out of curiosity, what is the difference if I install it through `conda install -c conda-forge pyferret` or `conda create -n FERRET -c conda-forge pyferret ferret_datasets --yes`. Thank you for answering my questions by the way. Unfortunately my account is too new to upvote yet.

Comment: @RSM `conda install ...` will install in an existing env, which you can specify using the `--name|-n` argument. The `conda create ...` will create a new env and install whatever packages you specify. Note that you can still accept answers to your questions (check mark next to answers), which also gives some points as well.