# How do I run pyferret on Jupyter notebook or Spyder?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using `pyferret` which is Python module from NOAA/PMEL, which i installed in an Ubuntu subsystem in windows, following tutorial that's, [mentioned here](https://github.com/NOAA-PMEL/PyFerret/blob/master/README.md). Since it's a python module, i was wondering whether I'd be able to use it in Spyder or Jupyter notebook. However, what confuses me is that would it be possible to run a program in windows system, that i actually installed in an Ubuntu subsystem. I hope it makes sense.

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829961/conda-installation-of-environment-pyferret-unsuccessful) regarding this. But i am not sure if will be applicable in Ubuntu subsystem in windows. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.